# Url rewriting causes Magento admin to become inaccessible

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, magento

I have magento in a subdirectory in the root and if I set the secure base url and secure base url link to the correct shared ssl url to enable secure pages I have no problem in the FRONTEND. The pages displays as they should. However when I try to access the admin with the secure link below I cannot gain admittance.

For instance in the frontend: `http://mydomain.com/shop` becomes `http://mydomain.com` - which is correct.

`https://mydomain.sharedssl.com/shop/customer/account/login/` becomes 
`https://mydomain.sharedssl.com/customer/account/login/` - which is correct.

But then I can access admin with neither `https://mydomain.com/shop/index.php/admin/` nor `https://mydomain.com//index.php/admin/`

In the root directory I have this in my htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/shop(.*)
RewriteRule (.*) /shop/$1 [L]
```

and in the shop (Magento) I have the following:

```
############################################
## uncomment these lines for CGI mode
## make sure to specify the correct cgi php binary file name
## it might be /cgi-bin/php-cgi

#    Action php5-cgi /cgi-bin/php5-cgi
#    AddHandler php5-cgi .php

############################################
## GoDaddy specific options

#   Options -MultiViews

## you might also need to add this line to php.ini
##     cgi.fix_pathinfo = 1
## if it still doesn't work, rename php.ini to php5.ini

############################################
## this line is specific for 1and1 hosting

    #AddType x-mapp-php5 .php
    #AddHandler x-mapp-php5 .php

############################################
## default index file

    DirectoryIndex index.php

<IfModule mod_php5.c>

############################################
## adjust memory limit

#    php_value memory_limit 64M
    php_value memory_limit 128M
    php_value max_execution_time 18000

############################################
## disable magic quotes for php request vars

    php_flag magic_quotes_gpc off

############################################
## disable automatic session start
## before autoload was initialized

    php_flag session.auto_start off

############################################
## enable resulting html compression

    #php_flag zlib.output_compression on

###########################################
# disable user agent verification to not break multiple image upload

    php_flag suhosin.session.cryptua off

###########################################
# turn off compatibility with PHP4 when dealing with objects

    php_flag zend.ze1_compatibility_mode Off

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_security.c>
###########################################
# disable POST processing to not break multiple image upload

    SecFilterEngine Off
    SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>

############################################
## enable apache served files compression
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#gzip

    # Insert filter on all content
    ###SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
    # Insert filter on selected content types only
    #AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/css text/javascript

    # Netscape 4.x has some problems...
    #BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html

    # Netscape 4.06-4.08 have some more problems
    #BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip

    # MSIE masquerades as Netscape, but it is fine
    #BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html

    # Don't compress images
    #SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$ no-gzip dont-vary

    # Make sure proxies don't deliver the wrong content
    #Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>

############################################
## make HTTPS env vars available for CGI mode

    #SSLOptions StdEnvVars

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

############################################
## enable rewrites

    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on

############################################
## you can put here your magento root folder
## path relative to web root

    RewriteBase /


############################################
## workaround for HTTP authorization
## in CGI environment

    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

############################################
## always send 404 on missing files in these folders

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(media|skin|js)/

############################################
## never rewrite for existing files, directories and links

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

############################################
## rewrite everything else to index.php

    RewriteRule  ^(.*)$ /shop/index.php [L]



</IfModule>


############################################
## Prevent character encoding issues from server overrides
## If you still have problems, use the second line instead

    AddDefaultCharset Off
    #AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

<IfModule mod_expires.c>

############################################
## Add default Expires header
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#expires

    ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"

</IfModule>

############################################
## By default allow all access

    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all

############################################
## If running in cluster environment, uncomment this
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#etags

    #FileETag none
```

Could someone lend some assistance to getting this to work in the Magento backend?

Comment: Could you post the result of this request : `SELECT * FROM core_config_data WHERE path like '%url'`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in getting of `REQUEST_URI` environment variable value and checking it with `SCRIPT_FILENAME` and `SCRIPT_NAME` environment variables values. In your case REQUEST_URI is /index.php/stddadmin/ and SCRIPT_FILENAME with SCRIPT_NAME are equals to /shop/index.php and Magento unable to retrieve path info for controllers matching. So a cause of the problem is in adding of /index.php/ prefix to the request path and the Magento url generation has this value hardcoded for admin.

There are only two solutions to your problem:

1. Override method called `_updatePathUseRewrites` in `Mage_Core_Model_Store` model like in the following example:

   ```
    class Your_CustomModule_Model_Store extends Mage_Core_Model_Store 
    {
        protected _updatePathUseRewrites($url) 
        {
            return $url; // Return passed variable without adding index.php as prefix 
        }
    }
   ```

   In this case your admin panel will be available at /admin/ url, like usual frontend page.
2. Reorganize project structure for placing Magento in root folder or add symbolic links on each its file and folder in root.

Comment: Thank you for the responses. What I did was allow the shared ssl to stay as it was which allowed me to login into the backend, but also showed in the frontend. So I changed the main website unsecure and secure base urls and things began working.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the "Admin Rewrites" extension to get rid of "index.php" in backend URLs:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/clockworkgeek/extension/3692/clockworkgeek_adminrewrites

It enables URL rewrites in the backend and it works fine. The only con is that it is marked as "Beta", because it overrides "Mage_Core_Model_Store".